# Log4j2: The logs are not getting written to the file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

could you please help me out here, so i am creating the log4j2 programmatically using java, as i do not want the xml configuration, i have created a new logger which is named as **changelog** , The log file is getting created inside the path **/var/log/test/changelog.log** but nothing is getting written inside it.

**Sample code:**

```java
private static void configureLog4J() 
{
        ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel( Level.WARN);
        builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
        // create a console appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
            ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        builder.add( appenderBuilder );
        // create a rolling file appender
        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
            .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
            .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "10M"));
        appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("ChangeLogFile", "RollingFile")
            .addAttribute("fileName", "/var/log/test/changelog.log")
            .addAttribute("filePattern", "/var/log/test/changelog-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz")
            .add(layoutBuilder)
            .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        // create the new logger
        builder.add( builder.newLogger( "changelog", Level.DEBUG )
            .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "ChangeLogFile" ) )
             );

        builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.WARN )
            .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "ChangeLogFile" ) ) );
      LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());     
    }
```

After calling the above method, i am getting the logger by below:

```java
final Logger changelog = LogManager.getLogger("changelog");
```

Answer (score 0):

*"After calling the above method, i am getting the logger by below"*: my guess is that the order of execution is inverse. First `LogManager.getLogger` is called (e.g. some static field initializer calls it) and then `configureLog4J`. You can check if this is the case by adding `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to your JVM's parameters and setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the `configureLog4J` method. If you get any output from the status logger, `LogManager.getLogger` has already been called.

If this is the case, a `LoggerContext` will already be attached to the classloader of your application when the execution of `configureLog4J` starts and `Configurator.initialize` will have no effect.

Replace it with:

```java
Configurator.reconfigure(builder.build());
```

to reconfigure the pre-existing `LoggerContext`.

**Remark:** `Configurator.reconfigure` will also work if no `LoggerContext` exists, so it is always safer to use this method.

Comment: Thank You, using the reconfigure method works for me also i have placed the getLogger method inside the static block.

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider accepting the answer (the big check mark beside the answer).